# Bash: Multiple npm install in the background give error, 'No space left on device'

Tags: bash, docker, npm, background-process

I am setting up docker on a google cloud compute machine, 1 vCPU and 3.75 GB ram.

If I simply run `docker-compose up --build`, it does work but the process is sequential and slow. So I am using this bash script so that I can build images in the background, and skip the usual sequential process.

```
command=$1
shift
jobsList=""
taskList[0]=""
i=0

#Replaces all the fluff with nothing, and we get our job Id
function getJobId(){
  echo "$(echo $STRING | sed s/^[^0-9]*// | sed s/[^0-9].*$//)"
}


for task in "$@"
do
  echo "Command is $command $task"
  docker-compose $command $task &> ${task}.text &
  lastJob=`getJobId $(jobs %%)`
  jobsList="$jobsList $lastJob"
  echo "jobsList is $jobsList"
  taskList[$i]="$command $task"
  i=$(($i + 1))
done

i=0
for job in $jobsList
do
  wait %$job
  echo "${taskList[$i]} completed with status $?"
  i=$(($i + 1))
done
```

and I use it in the following manner:

```
availableServices=$(docker-compose config --services)

while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]
do
  services+=$(echo "$line ")
done <<<"$availableServices"

./runInParallel.sh build $services
```

I string together available services in docker-compose.yml, and pass it to my script.

But the issue is eventually all the processes fail with the following error:

```
npm WARN tar ENOSPC: no space left on device, write
Unhandled rejection Error: ENOSPC: no space left on device, write
```

I checked inodes, and on `/dev/sda1` only 44% were used.

Here's my output for the command `df -h`:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            1.8G     0  1.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs           370M  892K  369M   1% /run
/dev/sda1       9.6G  9.1G  455M  96% /
tmpfs           1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0       55M   55M     0 100% /snap/google-cloud-sdk/64
/dev/loop2       55M   55M     0 100% /snap/google-cloud-sdk/62
/dev/loop1       55M   55M     0 100% /snap/google-cloud-sdk/63
/dev/loop3       79M   79M     0 100% /snap/go/3095
/dev/loop5       89M   89M     0 100% /snap/core/5897
/dev/loop4       90M   90M     0 100% /snap/core/6130
/dev/loop6       90M   90M     0 100% /snap/core/6034
/dev/sda15      105M  3.6M  101M   4% /boot/efi
tmpfs           370M     0  370M   0% /run/user/1001
```

and here's the output for `df -i`

```
Filesystem      Inodes  IUsed  IFree IUse% Mounted on
udev            469499    385 469114    1% /dev
tmpfs           472727    592 472135    1% /run
/dev/sda1      1290240 636907 653333   50% /
tmpfs           472727      1 472726    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           472727      8 472719    1% /run/lock
tmpfs           472727     18 472709    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0       20782  20782      0  100% /snap/google-cloud-sdk/64
/dev/loop2       20680  20680      0  100% /snap/google-cloud-sdk/62
/dev/loop1       20738  20738      0  100% /snap/google-cloud-sdk/63
/dev/loop3        9417   9417      0  100% /snap/go/3095
/dev/loop5       12808  12808      0  100% /snap/core/5897
/dev/loop4       12810  12810      0  100% /snap/core/6130
/dev/loop6       12810  12810      0  100% /snap/core/6034
/dev/sda15           0      0      0     - /boot/efi
tmpfs           472727     10 472717    1% /run/user/1001
```

Comment: Try *docker images -a* and remove unused images.

Comment: Perhaps pruning the system can also be a good idea

Comment: @AlexandreFenyo `docker images` without `-a` will show you "dangling" images (with a `<none>` label).  Adding `-a` shows some implementation details which are confusing if you don't understand what you're looking for, and doesn't actually help you find lost space.

Comment: Hey everyone, I forgot to mention, I did try pruning the system. That didn't help, eventually, all the processes fail. I did try it on my local machine, and it worked really well. I think I need to read more on how do background processes work and may be based on that I'll use a bit more powerful gcp instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your `df -h` output, root directory (/dev/sda1) has only 455MB free space.

Whenever you run docker build, the docker-client (CLI) will send all the contents of the Dockerfile directory to docker-daemon which builds the image.

So, for example, if you have three services each with 300MB directories, you can build them sequentially with 455MB available free space, but to build them all at the same time you need 300MB*3 amount of free space for docker-daemon to cache and build the images.

Comment: Hi, sorry, it's been long. So since then, I've tried to add storage, but this has been a continuous issue for me. Can you give me any insights into how do I go about fixing this?

Comment: Try passing docker-compose build args to reduce the space consumption(https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/build/), something like `./runInParallel.sh "build --compress  --force-rm" $services` 

Or check if /dev/sda has more than 50% free space available before running `docker-compose $command $task &> ${task}.text`